# Hurwitz Constant - Proof of Lemma 6.1.1. in Esmonde and Murty's Problems in Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am studying from Esmonde & Murty's book, *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory*. I'm having trouble in the last step in the proof of the first Lemma in Chapter 6. Here $K$ is a number field of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathcal{O}$ is its ring of integers.

> **Lemma 6.1.1.** There is a constant $H_K$ such that given $\alpha \in K$, $\exists\, \beta \in \mathcal{O}$, and a non-zero integer $t$, with $|t| \leq H_K$, such that
>   $$
> |N(t\alpha - \beta)| < 1.
> $$

The proof given in the book runs this way:

> Let $\{ \omega_1,\dots,\omega_n \}$ be an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}$. $\alpha \in K$
>   so there is a non-zero integer $c$ such that $c \alpha \in \mathcal{O}$. So we can write
>   $$
> \alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \omega_i
> $$
>   where $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $L \in \mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer, which we will specify later.
>   Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $L$ equal parts. Then, $[0,1]^n$ will be divided into $L^n$ subcubes. Define
>   $\varphi : \alpha \mathbb{Z} \to [0,1]^n$ by
>   $$
> \varphi(t \alpha) = (\{ t c_1\},\dots,\{ tc_n \})
> $$
>   where $t$ is an integer and $\{ \cdot \}$ denotes the fractional part. Let $t$ run from $0$ to $L^n$. By the
>   pigeonhole principle, there exist $t_1, t_2$ in this range such that $t_1 \alpha$ and $t_2 \alpha$
>   are mapped to the same subcube. So, $| \{ t_1 c_i \} - \{ t_2 c_i \} | \leq 1 / L$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$. Let
>   $$
> \beta = \sum_{i=1}^n ([t_1 c_i] - [t_2 c_i]) \omega_i
> $$
>   where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function. Let $t = t_1 - t_2$. Then,
>   \begin{align*}
> |N(t\alpha - \beta)| &= \left| N\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (\{ t_1 c_i \} - \{ t_2 c_i \}) \omega_i \right) \right|\\
> &= \left| \prod_{j = 1}^n \sigma_j \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (\{ t_1 c_i \} - \{ t_2 c_i \}) \omega_i \right) \right|\\
> &\leq \prod_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n | (\{ t_1 c_i \} - \{ t_2 c_i \}) \sigma_j(\omega_i) |\\
> &\leq \frac{1}{L^n} \prod_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n | \sigma_j(\omega_i) |
> \end{align*}
>   where the $\sigma_j$ are the $n$ embeddings of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
>   Let $H_K = \prod_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n | \sigma_j(\omega_i) |$. If $L^n > H_K$
>   then $|N(t \alpha - \beta)| < 1$. Also, $|t| \leq L^n$, so if we choose $L = H_K^{1/n}$ we are done.

It is not clear to me how we are done by choosing $L = H_K^{1/n}$. I need $L^n > H_K$ to get $N(t\alpha - \beta) < 1$, but $L = H_K^{1/n} \Rightarrow L^n = H_K$, so these two conditions on $L$ are incompatible. Also, $L$ is a natural number so I also need to show that $H_K^{1/n}$ is a natural number. What steps am I missing in this proof?

EDIT : The book says that the constant $H_K$ is called the Hurwitz constant, hence my title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof itself needs fixing.  It should read:

> If we take $L^n > \prod_{j=1}^n(\sum_{i=1}^n |\omega_i^{(j)}|)$, then
>   $$|N(t\alpha - \beta)| < 1.$$
>   Furthermore, since $0 \leq t_1, t_2 \leq L^n$, we have $|t| \leq L^n$.  Thus, if we choose $H_K = L^n$, we are done.

Comment: Thank you! If I may ask another question, how can I show that $H_K$ is independent of the integral basis chosen earlier?

Comment: I think the proof gives you "a" constant, not "the" constant, because that the constant in the proof is neither minimal for the property nor is it independent of the integral basis chosen.

Comment: I see, so the term "constant" would be misnomer for $H_K$?

Comment: Right, in the sense that $H_K$ as defined here is not  a well-defined invariant of the field.  But certainly it can be made so by defining it to be the minimum such integer with the required property.