# In Algebraic number theory, is the Hurwitz constant remain same if we consider another integral base?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In the proof of lemma in [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887976/hurwitz-constant-proof-of-lemma-6-1-1-in-esmonde-and-murtys-problems-in-alge#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20constant%20H,%E2%88%92%CE%B2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887976/hurwitz-constant-proof-of-lemma-6-1-1-in-esmonde-and-murtys-problems-in-alge#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20constant%20H,%E2%88%92%CE%B2))%7C%3C1.
The Hurwitz constant is not free of elements from the chosen integral basis. So if we consider another integral basis have we another Hurwitz constant or do we have the same constant?
But I have seen that this constant is standard one.
I have not found any conclusion about that. Please help!